# threw it (out) into the hallway

Tags: grammar

I grabbed the ringing phone and threw it (out) into the hallway.

(I'm in a hotel room, and the door into my room is open.)

Is it correct include "out"?

Comment: Welcome, Chicalaos! We would normally include *out*, whether the door was already open or not. But we might not include it the door was wide open and you were standing nearby, or if  there was already a heap of things in the hallway, because we would already understand the layout or process. And we wouldn't include it if you had already thrown a table-lamp out of the *window*, because the repeated 'out' would be misleading. I had never thought about this!

Answer (score 1):

Both "threw it into the hallway" and "threw it out into the hallway" are correct and sound fairly normal.  There isn't a lot of difference in meaning between them, either, so they're basically interchangeable.

When you include "out", you are emphasizing a bit more that you are throwing it for the deliberate purpose of getting it out of your room, but in most cases for this sort of thing that's assumed anyway, so it's only a small difference in feel, really.

Comment: Agreed: *out* emphasizes that it comes from somewhere (the room), *into* explains where it ends up. With enough context, you could omit *into the hallway* and just say *threw it out (of the room)*.